# Windows 7 hosted network use one adapter to receive and second adapter to create hostednetwork

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, netsh

Is it possible to use one WiFi adapter just for connecting to router to catch the WiFi. Then, use the 2nd adapter to create hosted network in windows?

The following commands do not seem to have an option to choose a particular adapter:
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid= key=
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Background of the Problem and need for Solution:
There are 2 adapters one very powerful and one weaker one. However, the access point is located quite far and both adapters do not catch the signal that well. But, when the first adapter is set to 802.11ac only mode, it catches the signal good and stable. But, if the 802.11ac mode is not set in the driver properties page, it selects 802.11 n by default which catches poor signal and stays connected but says no internet or limited.

Then, if hostednetwork is started, by default windows starts hosted network on that adapter and since it is set to 802.11ac, other devices which are not 802.11ac cannot connect to this hosted network.

Hence, if we can start hosted network with 2nd adapter that is 802.11 b/g/n, other devices could connect to it.

Please provide any hints or tips or alternative solutions scenarios. Let me know if the questions is not clear.

Temporary solution:
I was able to get internet to other devices by using Ethernet cable and sharing this internet with a new computer and then starting hosted network on this new computer which has 802.11 b/g/n adapter.

But, it seems unreasonable to leave running 2 machines just to create a hostednetwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Solution:

I figured out the following work around.

1) Disable other network adapters except the one you want to start hostednetwork on.

2) Execute: netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyWiFi key=abcde12345

3) Execute: netsh wlan start hostednetwork

4) Execute: netsh wlan show

It should create a new Local Area Connection.

Now, enable the other adapter and enable Internet Sharing to allow the new Local Area Connection.

If all goes well, now the newly hosted local area connection should provide internet access to WiFi devices.