# Hostednetwork on Windows 10 with 2 Wi-Fi adapters?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, netsh

Recently I purchased a USB Wi-Fi adapter that's capable of connecting to 5GHz Wi-Fi networks, for use with my old notebook which only has a 2.4GHz adapter built-in. I intend to share the connected 5GHz network with other 2.4GHz devices around me, so naturally I thought of using the USB one (adapter name "Wi-Fi 2") to receive and the built-in one (adapter name "Wi-Fi") as hotspot.

Unfortunately info is scarce on how Windows handles multiple adapters of the same type. I've searched and read through SuperUser and other sites, and the closest-related question is this one: [LINK: SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1081777/windows-7-hosted-network-use-one-adapter-to-receive-and-second-adapter-to-create). It indicates I have to disable/unplug the USB adapter while setting up hostednetwork for the built-in one, which I did.

I followed what it said up to the last step, where it lists a new "Local Area Connection" adapter, and the designated SSID shows. However, when I go to Properties-Sharing and set "Home networking connection" to "Wi-Fi 2", "Wi-Fi 2" stops working. It says "no internet" in the system tray, refuses to connect to any valid Wi-Fi access point I want it to, and from the adapter settings, it seems to be connected to the hotspot shared by "Wi-Fi", forming a self-loop.

[image: LINK: image]

I'm out of ideas at this point. Is there a setting I've missed or executed the wrong way?

P.S. I originally intended to post more pics illustrating the situation, but I'm new to SU and has no rep for that. Sorry for making it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the latest Windows 10 Version with the Settings->Network & Internet -> **"Mobile hotspot"** option seems to work better than any command line or dialogues.